# Disable cache warning for Pixi loader

Tags: javascript, caching, warnings, pixi.js

While loading several sprite atlases with the PixiJS loader I get this warning:

`Texture added to the cache with an id [SomeID] that already had an entry`

Since there are some assets that are in two atlases I get where this is coming from, but would it be possible to catch, ignore or disable this warning via code (not just ignore all warnings in console)?

**Solution**

Thanks to @Shawn's answer I ended up installing preprocess-loader and adding this code to my vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('preprocess-loader')
            .test(/\.[js|ts]/)
            .include.add(/pixi\.js/).end()
            .use('preprocess-loader')
                .loader('preprocess-loader')
                .options({DEBUG:false})
                .end()
    }
}
```

Having both `.test()` part and the `.include` part is a bit redundant, but doesn't hurt either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning's are only logged in two places --

Texture - 
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/f913327e55897d50e37c5c3addee468aeb8a0cb8/src/core/textures/Texture.js#L498

Basetexture - 
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/f6f00047d6c523df2aa366cf3745eb831cec6ec5/src/core/textures/BaseTexture.js#L807

If you look a few lines above either call, you can see what looks like a preprocessing directive fir conditional compilation that should only include that code if you're in DEBUG mode.
E.g.:

```
// @if DEBUG
      <test for error and warn>
// @endif
```

See an example of a preprocessor here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/preprocess

Weirdly, I don't see that library in their package.json, so I'm unsure if that preprocessor logic is even live.  Based on the scripts from the package.json and the lack of other preprocessors in the code, I doubt that preprocessor logic is being used.

So if you don't want to address the resource collision causing the warning you could either (i) enable conditional compilation, thereby triggering those preprocessor if statements, then run the code in a mode other than debug mode or (ii) just go into the code you're using and comment out the two console.warn statements (i.e., those two lines I linked at the beginning).

Option (ii) seems a bit easier.  :)

**Edit/Update:**

Fleshing out option (i) with info in your response, Arno:

Here are some webpack loaders that (if their docs are to be believed) add conditional preprocessing:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-preprocessor-loader
https://www.npmjs.com/package/preprocess-loader

According to the vue-cli docs, you can add new loaders as described in this link:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader

Example:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // GraphQL Loader
    config.module
      .rule('graphql')
      .test(/\.graphql$/)
      .use('graphql-tag/loader')
        .loader('graphql-tag/loader')
        .end()
  }
}
```

It appears as if it's generating a webpack config via an imperative api provided by [this library](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain).

So if you really need to get those warnings out of there, I would suggest (1) add one of those pre-processor webpack integrations, then (2) see if you can add the new webpack loader via the methods described in the docs.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The second option is a no go for me since I don't want to touch any files in the npm folder.
The first option looks elegant, but I'm using vue-cli-service in combination with TypeScript compiler to build everything. Even when installing preprocess manually I have no clue on where to put the preprocess options. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm.. added my final solution to the question.